# Cursor with one phone number for each contact

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter

I know how to get contact names and numbers in a cursor, but when I put them on a listview I get multiple numbers for the same contact in separate lines, i.e. if a contact has more than one number, all these numbers are displayed. How can I select only one number for each contact?

```
Uri uri = Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = { Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER, Phone._ID };
String sortOrder = Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, sortOrder);
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, and you want to show only one number per `DISPLAY_NAME` disregarding all others, you can use this hack:

```
String selection = "1) GROUP BY (" + Phone.DISPLAY_NAME;
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, selection , null, sortOrder);
```

**edit** Short explanation: it's kind of sql-injection: it will insert 1 in `WHERE` part of the query, making it always true, and add `GROUP BY`, unsupported by `managedQuery()`

Comment: Wow, this actually worked! Thanks! So how does my whole SELECT statement look with this? I mean where does 1 come in? Also you mention that this is a hack, is this an acceptable way to use? I.e. could I suffer in the future if I need to expand the code?

Comment: as I mentioned, it is sql-injection - so if google decides to restrict `selection`, it might stop working. However it seems as it was left the way it is now intentionally.

Comment: Does this mean you can use other sql statements in the `selection`, like for example `LIMIT`?

Comment: `LIMIT` can be put in sortOrder, since it should be put after `ORDER BY` statement, e.g. `String sortOrder = Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC" + " LIMIT 10";`